# Why is $\int_S^T f dB_t$ (Itô integral) $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

In Oksendal's book, in Theorem 3.2.1, the author states that $\int_S^T f dB_t$ is $\mathcal{F}_T$-measurable. In the proof he says that since it holds for elementary functions, when we take the limits we obtain this for all $f$ with some special properties.

There's a theorem stating that

> the *pointwise* limit of a measurable function, is also measurable.

The problem is that the limit we're using in the definition of the Itô integral is with respect to the L2 norm, and convergence in Lp norms doesn't not imply pointwise convergence...

Therefore, how does one can simply take the limits and get a $\mathcal{F}_T$-measurable?

Comment: Note that $\int_S^T f\,dB_t$ is only $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable for $t \ge T$.  Or maybe your $t$ was meant to be a $T$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convergence in $L^p$ norms implies pointwise convergence along a subsequence, though, so that gives the measurability you need.  Suppose $(X_n) \rightarrow X$ in $L^1$, then we can take a subsequence such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}[|X_{n_k}-X|] < \infty.$  By the monotone convergence theorem, we have $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}[|X_{n_k}-X|] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{k=1}^\infty|X_{n_k}-X|\right] < \infty $$ so $\sum_{k=1}^\infty|X_{n_k}-X| < \infty$ almost surely, and hence $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} |X_{n_k}-X| = 0$ almost surely so we have $(X_{n_k}) \rightarrow X$ pointwise a.s.  In particular, if each $X_n$ was measurable, this shows that $X$ is also measurable.

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, this relies on the fact that the $\mathcal F_t$ is complete.  This is included in Definition 3.1.2 of Oksendal's book.

Comment: Since the sequence converges only almost surely, you will need to assume that the filtration is complete.

Comment: I actually don't think you need completeness.  The set of outcomes for which $X_{n_k}$ converges is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable, whether or not the filtration is complete.  The Borel-Cantelli argument shows that this set has measure 1.  Completeness doesn't hurt, of course.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I still have a few questions though. 1) - How do we from a L1 convergence get that boundedness for the series? 2) - What's the issue that demands completeness? Why should we worry about it?

Comment: 1) We get the series is bounded by taking a subsequence.  Since the sequence converges in $L^1$, for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we can find $n_k$ such that $\mathbb{E}[|X_{n_k}-X|] < 2^{-k}$.
2) The issue is that in general a pointwise almost everywhere limit of measurable functions is only measurable if the $\sigma$-algebra is complete.  Since we typically work with the completion of the filtration, this isn't really a problem here.

Comment: Thanks @user6247850 ;)

Comment: @user6247850 I assume in the MCT step you go $\infty >  \lim_{N \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[\sum_{k=1}^N \lvert X_{n_k} - X \rvert]  = \mathbb{E}[\lim_{N \to \infty}  \sum_{k=1}^N \lvert X_{n_k} - X \rvert]  = \mathbb{E}[\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lvert X_{n_k} - X \rvert] $, but how can you interchange limits and expectation without presupposing that the partial sums converge pointwise a.s.?

Comment: @goblinb Sorry, I'm not quite sure I understand the question?  Everything is monotone, so the partial sums necessarily converge at least in an extended real sense.  I suppose another way of writing it with explicit limits is $$\mathbb{E}[\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^N |X_{n_k}-X|] = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[\sum_{k=1}^N |X_{n_k}-X|] = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^N \mathbb{E}[|X_{n_k}-X|] \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}[|X_{n_k}-X|] < \infty$$

Comment: @user6247850 I'm probably confused, then. The limit of the nonnegative, monotone sequence of random variables in the monotone convergence theorem may be infinite? I'll have to repeat the proof. Thanks